# How to ignore double quote in StringBuffer

Tags: java, xml

I am using StringBuffer to dynamically append the string, using \ for ignoring single double (") 
but the proper result is not coming. Please help

Now

```
       "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
        <tv time=\"10\" name=\"Main Gate\" id=\"9410\" device=\"smartTV\"> 
           <playlist name=\"Welcome\" id=\"56\">
           </playlist>
        </tv>"
```

Expected

```
       "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <tv time="10" name="Main Gate" id="9410" device="smartTV"> 
           <playlist name="Welcome" id="56">
           </playlist>
        </tv>"
```

Below in java code

```
     StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("<?xml version=\"1.0\" 
                                               encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
      stringBuffer.append("<tv time=\"10\" device-name=\""+ 
                   device.getName() +"\" "
            + "device-id=\""+device.getDeviceHardId()+"\" 
                   device=\""+device.getDeviceType()+"\">");

    Playlist playlist = device.getPlaylist();
    if(playlist !=  null){

        stringBuffer.append("<playlist name=\""+playlist.getName()+"\" 
                 id=\""+playlist.getId() +"\">");
        stringBuffer.append("</playlist>");
    }

    stringBuffer.append("</tv>");
```

Comment: Please show  your actual code.

Comment: try to print it out in console the `\"` included could be used by java to include the `double quotes`

Comment: Could you show the code to clarify what you are doing?

Comment: If you want to produce XML then you probably should not be using string concatenation, but an actual XML API instead. It's way to easy to repeat the sins of wrong encoding otherwise, one of which you're currently running into.

Comment: simple string char replace should get you what you want.

Comment: Are you REALLY sure that your string contains those "`\`"? From your code, it shouldn't be the case. Have you tried to display it by `System.out.print(stringBuffer)`?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><hsc-tv sync-time="10" device-name="Hughes Reception" device-id="9410" device="smartTV"><playlist name="Hello August" id="56"></playlist></hsc-tv>

Comment: @Aditchoudhary there is no way for your code to produce that output. `tv` won't magically transform itself into `hsc-tv`. But most importantly: what is the problem with that output? What else do you expect and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

produce type should be @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })

convert StringBuffer into String...

Now working fine for me.

```
@GET
@Path("xml")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
@Produces({  MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public String GetXMl(){
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("<tv name=\"sony\"></tv>");
  String xml =sb.toString();
  return xml;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as expected, escaping the string is the way to get actual quotes in your xml, the only question is what complier you are using to parse the string, Java takes escape characters as expected but if you are using so other type of editor it can handle it in a different way

Answer (score -1):

This is not a good practice. Instead of escaping the double quote everywhere why not use `replace()` method provided by String Object. Replace double quote with a unique identifier like '&quot'. At the end replace '&quot' with a double quote. Below snippet will demonstrate

```
    StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
    str.append("<?xml version=&quot1.0&quot encoding=&quotUTF-8&quot?><tv time=&quot10&quot name=&quot"+ device.getName() + "&quot id=&quot" + device.getDeviceHardId() + "&quot device=&quot"+ device.getDeviceType() + "&quot>");
    Playlist playlist2 = device.getPlaylist();
    if (playlist2 != null) {
        str.append("<playlist name=&quot" + playlist2.getName() + "&quot id=&quot" + playlist2.getId()+"&quot></playlist></tv>");
    }
    System.out.println(str.toString().replace("&quot", "\"")); //Will print the desired XML
```

Still, if you need your implementation, below code should work.

```
     StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
     stringBuffer.append("<tv time=\"10\" name=\"" + device.getName() + "\" " + "id=\"" + device.getDeviceHardId() + "\" device=\"" + device.getDeviceType() + "\">");
     Playlist playlist1 = device.getPlaylist();
     if (playlist1 != null) {
         stringBuffer.append("<playlist name=\"" + playlist1.getName() + "\" id=\"" + playlist1.getId() + "\">");
         stringBuffer.append("</playlist>");
     }
     stringBuffer.append("</tv>");
```

Edit : It's not a solution, it's a workaround. &qout is an example. Can be any unique stringset

Comment: Sorry, but this is really a bad advice. What if your XML contains the entity reference for double quote `&quot;` as is? Using a special marker string has always the flaw that you need some escape mechanism in order to be able to use the marker string literally as content.

Comment: @vanje '&quot' is just an example. We can use something unique. A combination of special characters might not create conflict.